# how can we have the special charecters as a variable name in sas 9.3

Tags: sas

I would like to know if it is possbile to have the european letters., 
Ä Å Ö as a part of variable name in SAS 9.3. 
It is possible in SAS enterprise guide but I couldnt do that in SAS 9.3 .,

```
data dsn;
input År name$;
datalines;
1 fgh
2 hjy
;
run;
```

and the log details from 9.3 are

38   data dsn;
39   input År name$;
ERROR: The name År is not a valid SAS name.
40   datalines;

```
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.DSN may be incomplete.  When this step was
 stopped there were 0
         observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
  cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

and from enterprise guide..it works.

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.DSN has 2 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.02 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the settings of valid variable names - validvarname. It tends to default to ANY in EG and V7 in SAS BASE.

```
Options validvarname=ANY;
```

Comment: Note that this isn't really a very good idea if you are sharing your code with others, as it means they can't use it unless they have the same option set - and this introduces additional issues (such as `PROC IMPORT` from excel/etc. allowing spaces and other characters).  But it is the answer to the question as asked.